# How come I have lazy loaded entity on eagerly declared entity when saving?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Here's my mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "saved_entity")
public class SavedEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_first_entity", nullable = false)
    private FirstEmbeddedEntity firstEmbeddedEntity;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_second_entity", nullable = false)
    private SecondEmbeddedEntity secondEmbeddedEntity;

    // ... constructor / getter / setter
}
```

And I'm saving this through a JpaRepository directly in the controller and return the result to be marshalled by Jackson (data is coming from an AngularJS app)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private SavedEntityJpaRepository savedEntityJpaRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public SavedEntity saveEntity(@RequestBody SavedEntity savedEntity) {
        return this.savedEntityJpaRepository.save(savedEntity);
    }
}
```

What is weird is that `firstEmbeddedEntity` is correctly loaded after the "save", but `secondEmbeddedEntity` is a lazy loaded entity with a handler of type `org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer`.

What am I missing here? I don't get why two embedded entities declared the same way have different behaviour.

Should not JpaRepository's save action return an entity corresponding to the mapping?

Comment: How do you know `firstEmbeddedEntity` is correctly loaded after the save?

Comment: I'm debugging step by step, and have looked into objects from the debugger

Comment: now you mention it, a huge difference between my first embedded entity and the second is that the first doesn't embed more entities, where the second does.

Comment: Were you inside a transactional method while debugging?

Comment: Once the transaction closes those lazy entities will be loaded. BTW use a different wrapper to transfer your data from API.

Comment: I dont' think so. I've activated transaction with spring with `@EnableTransactionManagement` so I'm assuming Spring is creating a transaction per request

Comment: can you try @Transactional(rollbackOn = Throwable.class) annotation on general method?

Comment: @SüleymanK doesn't change the outcome. An exception is raised, but afterward when Jackson tries to serialize the entity and don't know what to do with a `JavassistLazyInitializer` (so it's too late, the transaction is already closed)

Comment: you can use "@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})" for JavassistLazyInitializer

Comment: @SüleymanK that's what I've done, but the problem is my controller returns a half loaded entity, so it's unusable by my frontend application. For now I'm doing another call to the backend to load the entity once more (so it's loaded correctly with every EAGER entities), but that's not very clean...